# How to grab a portion of an LDAP string into a variable (Powershell)

Tags: powershell

I am able to get the full LDAP path into a variable $strPath and it will return a result such as:

> LDAP://CN=computername,OU=City,OU=Servers,OU=###,DC=dom,DC=ain,DC=com
>   or in other locations it could look like:
>   LDAP://CN=computername,OU=Servers,OU=##,DC=dom,DC=ain,DC=com

I want to return only the ##, ### or #### value (it can be either two, three or four characters) which is our district code.

So some computer objects have a city name in their LDAP string while others do not (depending on the size of the district), and the district code can be two, three or four characters long.

I'm guessing I want to do something like find text **"Servers,OU="** and remove everything including and before that and also remove text **",DC=dom,DC=ain,DC=com"** to get my final variable.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may be interested in the ADName module I wrote:

https://github.com/Bill-Stewart/PowerShell-ADName

For your first example, the OU code is the 4th element from the right:

```
LDAP://CN=computername,OU=City,OU=Servers,OU=###,DC=dom,DC=ain,DC=com
```

So for example, you can write this:

```
(Get-ADName "LDAP://CN=computername,OU=City,OU=Servers,OU=###,DC=dom,DC=ain,DC=com" -Split -ValuesOnly)[-4]
```

The `-Split` parameter splits the LDAP path into an array, and `-ValuesOnly` omits the `CN=`, `OU=`, `DC=`, etc. The `[-4]` means "return the 4th element from the end of the array."

Comment: So this leads to more questions (sorry I'm a novice)
I am writing a script which needs this district code, so I would need to get $strPath from my script - run the command you provided within Get-ADpathname.ps1, then return the new variable back to my script for further use. How would be the best way to do that?

Comment: You can just run `Get-ADPathname` as a command in your existing script, provided you copy the `Get-ADPathname.ps1` to a directory in your `Path` (as you would with any scripts or other executables you run all the time).

Comment: The link is no longer valid. @Bill_Stewart, do you happen to have a copy of that kicking around anymore?

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this:

```
$ldapString = "LDAP://CN=computername,OU=Servers,OU=##,DC=dom,DC=ain,DC=com"
$temp = $ldapString.Split(",=")
$districtCode = $temp[[array]::IndexOf($temp,"DC") - 1]
```

It works with both and no extra imports. As long as you do not have a district code that is "DC".